# Unity2d Player rotate in accordance with mouse position

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, 2d

I've tried Atan2, I've tried whatever is euler angles, I've tried everything Unity3d's site, and I get three results:

I can move my mouse slowly, I can move it at the speed of light, the rotation of the player is fixed, either looking up, or down.

The player rotates, not looking at the mouse though. It's as though it's doing it's own thing.

It rotates on anything but the z axis.

I'm completely out of ideas, completely out. I've tried everything, including downloading several slither.io knockoff projects to figure out how they accomplish the task, but *none of them work*.

If you're having trouble grasping what I need to achieve, well, I have no code at this moment. But there's a website with the same thing I'm trying to accomplish.

Play surviv.io Look at how the player rotates in accordance with the mouse. That's what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this, but....

The code below should work if you have a background screen that can be raycasted against so the ray collides with it. Then play around a bit with the coordinates in the Transform.LookAt().

Basically it does these steps.

1 - Fire a ray from the screen to the mouse position, save a reference to whatever is hit in the 'Hit' variable.

2 - If anything was hit, rotate the players transform to look where it hit.

```
public LayerMask RaycastCollidableLayers;
public RaycastHit Hit;
public float CheckDistance = 200f;
public Transform Player;

void PerformRaycast(){
//Set up ray
ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
//Fire ray
Physics.Raycast(ray, out Hit, CheckDistance + 0.1f, RaycastCollidableLayers);
if (Hit.collider == null)
{
    //Debug.Log("Raycast hit nothing");
    return;
}
else //Ray hit something
    {
    //Look at Hit.point on x and y axes.
    Player.LookAt(new Vector3(Hit.point.x, Hit.point.y, 0f), Vector3.up); //Ignoring z axis, may need to be another axis. Vector3.up sets the up direction.
    }
}
```

Sources:

- Transform.LookAt: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html
- Camera.ScreenPointToRay: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenPointToRay.html

Let me know how it works for you.